# probability of dependent events of box of balls

Tags: probability

I have a box full of $N$ unique balls. The first time, I pick $k$ balls out of this box (I inspect them and put them back). On the second time, I also pick $k$ balls out of the same box (that has $N$ balls with $k$ previous uncovered balls). After these two draws, how many balls did I uncover?

My solution to this is
The number of uncovered balls =  $k/N + k/(N-k)$?

Is this correct?

Comment: You are being asked to calculate the number of uncovered balls, not the probability for selecting them. Question: Is it possible to select the same balls on both draws? If you do, you have only uncovered $k$ balls (the same $k$ balls twice). Or, maybe you select only one new ball and all the rest are previously uncovered balls. The answer may be anywhere between $k$ and $2k$. Or if you cannot select the same ball on both draws. Then you are always going to wind up with $2k$ uncovered balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach with linearity of expectation.

Given a specific ball in question, the probability that it was not seen in either draw is $(1-\frac{k}{N})^2$.  The probability then that it was seen at least once is $1$ minus that.

Now, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of balls that were seen at least once is then:

$$N(1-(1-\frac{k}{N})^2)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is clear, but why did we multiply by N in the last equation? And if I have number of draws, S, would the equation be N(1-K/N)^S))?

Comment: @Mona you skipped an extra `(1-` there.  As for why we multiplied by $N$, we recognize that the random variable counting the total number of uncovered balls is very simply the sum of all the $N$ random variables, each of which describing whether or not their own corresponding ball has been uncovered or not, each of which are identically distributed.

Comment: Yes, I understand now... Thank you very much for your help. Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can pick the same balls on both draws, this problem is anything but easy. In this case, you are not going to have a constant result, but rather an expected value:

The probability of choosing exactly $r$ of the same balls and $k-r$ different balls is:

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{k}{r}\dbinom{N-k}{k-r}}{\dbinom{N}{k}}$$

When you choose $r$ of the same balls and $k-r$ different balls, you have uncovered $2k-r$ distinct balls.

So, the expected value for the number of balls uncovered is:

$$\sum_{r=0}^k (2k-r)\cdot \dfrac{\dbinom{k}{r}\dbinom{N-k}{k-r}}{\dbinom{N}{k}} = \dfrac{(N-1)!(N-2k)!\left(2kN\dbinom{N-k}{k}-k(N-2k+1)\dbinom{N-k}{k-1}\right)}{\dbinom{N}{k}((N-k)!)^2}$$

(I used Wolframalpha to simplify this).